# • How CPU identify that which device is sending the request? • How CPU decide which action should be taken for each request?

Tags: operating-systems

•   How CPU identifies which device is sending the request?
•   How CPU decide which action should be taken for each request?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  We discourage "one-line" questions.  Instead, please elaborate on your question following the guidelines in [help/how-to-ask]: give us context what you're referring to, show us what research you've done, tell us your thoughts.  It's not clear what you mean by "the request"; what request, or what kind of request, are you referring to?  Please give us more context.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-CPU-identify-that-which-device-is-sending-the-request-How-CPU-decide-which-action-should-be-taken-for-each-request

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are asking how devices communicate with the x86 CPUs.

The motherboard has different types of slots (USB, PCI-Express, VGA, etc). It depends on what type of slot your device requests come from.

The motherboard hardwires the slots to pins on the IOAPIC of the processor.
[image: IOAPIC]

Devices communicate with the CPU through the IOAPIC. The IOAPIC has several pins including the IRQs pins. Today, each IOAPIC manages 24 IRQs (0 to 23). Each slot/device on the motherboard is given an IRQ by hardwiring (an actual electrical line) the slot's pins to a pin on the IOAPIC.

IOAPIC means In Out Advanced Programmable Interrupt Controller. It is programmable which means that you can change what interrupt is fired by what IRQ. When the device wants to tell the CPU it has data ready or anything else, it triggers the IRQ line. The IOAPIC is programmed by the operating system (OS) (at boot) to fire a certain interrupt number when a certain IRQ occurs.

For example, if a PCI device like a network card receives data which is destined to the computer (the request contains the right MAC address), the network card was made to fire its IRQ. Its IRQ is hardwired to an IOAPIC pin. If the IOAPIC was programmed by the OS to fire interrupt 10 for this IRQ then interrupt 10 is fired.

Each CPU has an IDT (Interrupt Descriptor Table). The address of the bottom of the IDT is stored in the LIDT special register of the processor. The IDT is made of entries which are numbered from 0 to any number.

An IDT entry in C looks like (https://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Descriptor_Table):

```
struct IDTDescr {
   uint16_t offset_1; // offset bits 0..15
   uint16_t selector; // a code segment selector in GDT or LDT
   uint8_t zero;      // unused, set to 0
   uint8_t type_attr; // type and attributes, see below
   uint16_t offset_2; // offset bits 16..31
};
```

The offset is split into two parts which once put back together represents the address of the handler for this certain interrupt number. The CPU will calculate the position in RAM of an IDT entry by the formula `idt_base_address + (idt_entry_length * int_number)`. If interrupt 10 is fired then the formula becomes `idt_base_address + (8 * 10) = idt_base_address + 80`. The CPU will look 80 bytes after the base address of the IDT, it will take the offset found at that position, it will then jump at that address.

When the computer boots, the BIOS is programmed to check the motherboard's slots for devices. The BIOS then builds ACPI tables that it writes in RAM depending on what it finds. For example if it finds a Real Time Clock (RTC) on the motherboard it will write in RAM (https://wiki.osdev.org/AML)

```
Device (RTC)
{
    Name (_HID, EisaId ("PNP0B00"))  // _HID: Hardware ID
    Name (_CRS, ResourceTemplate ()  // _CRS: Current Resource Settings
    {
        IO (Decode16,
        0x0070,             // Range Minimum
        0x0070,             // Range Maximum
        0x01,               // Alignment
        0x08,               // Length
        )
        IRQNoFlags (){8}
     })
     OperationRegion (CMS0, SystemCMOS, Zero, 0x40)
     Field (CMS0, ByteAcc, NoLock, Preserve)
     {
         RTSE,   8, 
         Offset (0x02), 
         RTMN,   8, 
         Offset (0x04), 
         RTHR,   8, 
         Offset (0x06), 
         RTDY,   8, 
         RTDE,   8
     }
}
```

This language is known as AML which is written in binary form in RAM. The OS needs to learn interpreting this language to determine what devices are plugged on the computer. These AML entries contain the IRQ that the device uses and some information on the device. The OS will use this to set up a handler for that device. Basically, if the OS finds a network card on a certain IRQ then it will setup this IRQ to a certain interrupt number which will point to a suitable handler for that device.

The OS communicates with devices using IO ports. It will use the ACPI tables to determine what device is plugged where and how to communicate with these devices. For every type of device (and any brand), the OS needs a driver. The driver can be either proprietary or open source (conventional). Very often manufacturers of devices will make their device respect certain conventions on how to communicate with them. This will widen the amount of OS which can "drive" their device and make it more user friendly (plug and play).

For example, if it finds a WIFI network card on a certain PCI slot, then it will setup a driver which will have certain special functions (depending on the type of device) that the OS can call. You can write drivers yourself and the OS is responsible to provide programming interfaces to ease the development of drivers and their installation in the kernel.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. I see many terms introduced in past decades. Several lost importance this millennium, which gets me wondering how contemporary/2020 SoCs handle "requests".